# Oracle Index with multiple Columns querying on single column

Tags: oracle, indexing

In a table in our Oracle installation we have a table with an index on two of the columns (X and Y).  If I do a query on the table with a where clause only touching column X, will Oracle be able to use the index?

For example:

Table Y:
 Col_A,
 Col_B,
 Col_C,

Index exists on (Col_A, Col_B)

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Y WHERE Col_A = 'STACKOVERFLOW';
```

Will the index be used, or will a table scan be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends.

You could check it by letting Oracle explain the execution plan:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR 
   SELECT * FROM Table_Y WHERE Col_A = 'STACKOVERFLOW';
```

and then

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
```

So, for example with

```
create table table_y (
  col_a varchar2(30),
  col_b varchar2(30),
  col_c varchar2(30)
);

create unique index table_y_ix on table_y (col_a, col_b);
```

and then a

```
explain plan for
  select * from table_y
  where col_a = 'STACKOVERFLOW';

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
```

The plan (on my installation) looks like:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |            |     1 |    51 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE_Y    |     1 |    51 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | TABLE_Y_IX |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("COL_A"='STACKOVERFLOW')
```

ID 2 shows you, that the index `TABLE_Y_IX` is indeed used for an `index range scan`.

If on another installation Oracle chooses to use the index is dependend on many things. It's Oracle's *query optimizer* that makes this decision.

**Update** If you feel you're be better off (performance wise, that is) if Oracle used the index, you might want to try the `+ index_asc(...)` (see  [index hint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF50406))

So in your case that would be something like

```
SELECT /*+ index_asc(TABLE_Y TABLE_Y_IX) */ * 
  FROM Table_Y 
 WHERE Col_A = 'STACKOVERFLOW';
```

Additionally, I would ensure that you have gathered statistics on the table and its columns. You can check the date of the last gathering of statistics with a

```
select last_analyzed from dba_tables where table_name = 'TABLE_Y';
```

and

```
select column_name, last_analyzed from dba_tab_columns where table_name = 'TABLE_Y';
```

If there are no statistics or if they're stale, make yourself familiar with the `dbms_stats` package to gather such statistics.

These statistics are the data that the *query optimizer* relies on heavily to make its decisions.

Comment: Perfect, that helps a lot.  As an aside, my installation reports a table scan, but at least I now have the ability to check.

Comment: Just wondering. Doesn't the execution plan selection depend on whether you are choosing the first or the second column in the index. That is if you are choosing the first column you get an index range scan but if you are selecting the second column you get a full table scan?

Comment: @Gisli: Oracle might choose to use the index for an [index skip scan](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/optimops.htm#PFGRF10105) in your scenario.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger, the links for tahiti and index hint are broken. Could you please update it.

Comment: @ajmalmhd04 I have updated the second broken link. I was unable to find the new destination for the old link, so I removed it. It's ironic that a vendor who sells the idea of a primary key is unable to keep their urls constant.